# Cannot make POST request (with data) with event trigger from outside component

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios

I am trying to use a click event from one component to trigger a method in another, and so far that works fine... except, the data that should be passed in my POST request doesn't get sent.

However, when I tested it by calling it in the component holding the API call method, it works fine.

Ideas?

Data being passed from Dashboard .vue -

```
// Data to be loaded into s3 bucket
this.s3Data.push([`Longitude: ${this.lng}, Latitude: ${this.lat}, Uncertainty Radius: ${this.uncertainty_radius} meters, Address: ${this.place_name}, Source: TEXT`])
this.s3Data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.s3Data))
```

Method to be called from Dashboard.vue -

```
uploadToS3() {
  axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/targetLocation/uploadLocationsToS3Bucket", this.s3Data,
      {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
},
```

Method trigger event from Applayout.vue -

HTML

```
<v-btn @click="uploadDataToS3" outlined dark data-test="end-tracking-button">End Tracking</v-btn>
```

JS

```
import Dashboard from "@/pages/Dashboard/desktop/Dashboard.vue";

uploadDataToS3() {
  Dashboard.methods.uploadToS3()
},
```

Comment: you can use eventBus to emit an event from Applayout and then catch it from Dashboard.vue followed by triggering the handler

Comment: @Amaarrockz An event bus to trigger the API call? I don't need to pass data, so I can use it to simply trigger it?

Comment: If there is any data u need to pass from here to there then go for it else not necessary

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best solution for this is to use [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

You will be able to call this and other methods from any component without the trouble of having to communicate between components with  `props` or `bus`.

**Further explanaiton:**

If you wants to connect to an api, the function doesn't need to be on a component.

If it is a function called by different components.. the best solution, in my opinion, is to create it in a mixins file and call it from every component who needs it.

Comment: To emit an event in one component from another component? How so?

Comment: If he wants to connect to an api, it doesn't need to be on the other component neither.  It is a function called by different components.. the best solution, in my opinion, is to create it in a mixins file and call it from every component which needs it.

Answer (score 0):

The flow your are trying should work. I suspect there is some error in a part you have not posted. But this is not the usual way this is done.

## The easy way

If there is a parent-child relation between the components (`Dashboard -> Applayout`) the usual way of communication is by emitting events in the child:

```
this.$emit('custom-event-name', { eventData:  'if needed' })
```

and handling the event in the parent:

```
<Dashboard @custom-event-name="uploadDataToS3" />
```

In this way you don't hard couple the components together, meaning that you can eventually insert other components between the parent and the child and you 'only' need to pass the event higher in the parent-child relation. As an added bonus, events are easier to inspect in the Vue dev tools extension.

---

## The elegant way

But the more elegant way is to use Vuex and if the components are siblings and you need to pass data between them i strongly recommend using Vuex. It is a little bit harder at fist but it is much easier to maintain and you will thank yourself for choosing this path later on for uncoupling external API calls and making them easier to reuse on other components.

You would need a store looking something like this:

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    neededData: '', 
    resultData: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    setNeededData (state, payload) {
      state.neededData = `Longitude: ${payload.lng}, Latitude: ${payload.lat}, Uncertainty Radius: ${payload.uncertainty_radius} meters, Address: ${payload.place_name}, Source: TEXT\n`
    },
    setresultData (state, payload) {
      state.someData = payload
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async uploadDataToS3 (context, data) {
      const result = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/targetLocation/uploadLocationsToS3Bucket",
        context.state.neededData,
        {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
      )
      context.commit('setResultData ', result.data)
    }
  }
})
export default store
```

Then update data from `Dasboard` to the store. You can do this on whatever element you interact with to obtain the data required in the API call.

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="dashboardData.lat" />
  <input type="text" v-model="dashboardData.lng" />
  <button type="button" @click="setData" />
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        dashboardData: {
          lat: '',
          lng: ''
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      setData () {
        this.$store.commit('setNeededData', this.dashboardData)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Then in the `Applayout` component you would do this:

```
  <button @click="$store.dispatch('uploadDataToS3', neededData)" />
```

To come full circle you would get the result data in the `Dashboard` component like this:

```
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['someData'])
  }
}
</script>
```

or just

```
this.$store.state.someData
```

But i like the previous version better because you can see at a glance what data you pull from a store by looking in the computed property.

Comment: This seems doable, except it needs to be  Applayout->Dashboard  and dashboard already has the data. I just need to use Applayout to trigger the method in Dashboard 

(which already happens with the current setup, BUT the data doesn't get added to the POST. The only I can make that work with the data is if I call the method from Dashboard, which I don't want to do)

Comment: I could pass the data to Applayout and the post that way, yes

Comment: @HelpTheNoob How do you get the `Dashboard` component used in `UploadDataToS3`? Are you by any chance reimporting an component with no data and running the function on that? The way you get a reference to a component is by setting a ref atribute `<Dashboard ref="dashboardRefName" />` and then use it in a method by accessing `this.$refs.dashboardRefName.uploadToS3()`. But you should really consider using the store. It gets useful fast.

Comment: I've added the import statement and where the data comes from. That should clarify things for you

Comment: Try using [refs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html), i suspect you are not getting the same component instance if you access the component like that.